# Use of dylib file instead of tbd is giving me error in Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, dylib

I am trying to use a Library which specifically needs me to use libz.tbd file however I am still using the Xcode 6.4 version because of some issue at my code end.

How to use dylib file instead to make this work.